# Post a zipped textfile to apache nifi

Tags: post, zip, apache-nifi

A compressed text file in zip format has to be sent to apache nifi via HTTP or HTTPS. There it has to be decompressed and stored on HDFS. The efforts so far are fruitless.

Test file is a zipped text document `blabla.txt`

---

**Python post**

```
import requests
requests.post('http://example.com/endpoint',
              files={'files': open('blabla.zip', 'rb')})
```

---

**Nifi process**

My best attemt is using the following Nifi processors:

- **HandleHttpRequest**
- **RouteOnAttribute** (filter on endpoint /endpoint)
  content of flowfile is:

  > --e313bde14db343d99c74fbb129fba9ac
  >   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="blabla.zip"
  >
  > PKh|�L��G
  >   blabla.txtK,NAB�)�&PKh|�L��G
  >   $ blabla.txt
  >   f�-.����<,����<,�PK\3
- **ExtractText**

  *file* = `^Content\-Disposition.*?(^PK.*)$.*?^\-\-.*?\-\-$`
  *file_name* = `^Content\-Disposition\: form\-data\; name\=\"files\"\; filename\=\"(.*?)\"`
- **ReplaceText**: replace .* by $(file) to replace the entire content of the flowfile by *file*. Flowfile content is now:

  > PKh|�L��G
  >   blabla.txtK,NAB�)�&PKh|�L��G
  >   $ blabla.txt
  >    f�-.����<,����<,�PK\3
- **UnpackContent** throws the following error:

  > 09:43:04 CEST - All Nodes - ERROR
  >   UnpackContent[id=d1973e21-d051-1530-ffff-fffff1485298] Unable to unpack StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=2d63555b-ff0f-4383-99d1-496df13c7a00,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1530878768408-1, container=default, section=1], offset=24932, length=201],offset=0,name=1054961836825343,size=201] due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from UnpackContent[id=d1973e21-d051-1530-ffff-fffff1485298]: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set; routing to failure: IOException thrown from UnpackContent[id=d1973e21-d051-1530-ffff-fffff1485298]: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set

---

**Without extract/replace**

- **HandleHttpRequest**
- **RouteOnAttribute** (filter on endpoint /endpoint)
  content of flowfile is:

  > --e313bde14db343d99c74fbb129fba9ac
  >   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="blabla.zip"
  >
  > PKh|�L��G
  >   blabla.txtK,NAB�)�&PKh|�L��G
  >   $ blabla.txt
  >   f�-.����<,����<,�PK\3
- **UnpackContent** yields the following error:

  > 09:04:16 CEST - All Nodes - ERROR 
  >   UnpackContent[id=4ffa337f-0a73-197a-9965-c1334338ebd8] Unable to unpack StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=93cad6cf-e19b-4d0b-9d2d-54e38b9b8bed,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1530878768408-1, container=default, section=1], offset=21130, length=312],offset=0,name=1052634174590117,size=312] due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from UnpackContent[id=4ffa337f-0a73-197a-9965-c1334338ebd8]: java.util.zip.ZipException: Unexpected record signature: 0X65632D2D; routing to failure: IOException thrown from UnpackContent[id=4ffa337f-0a73-197a-9965-c1334338ebd8]: java.util.zip.ZipException: Unexpected record signature: 0X65632D2D

Comment: Do you know what the file encoding of the zipped payload is?

Comment: If I open local zip file in notepad++ is says it is `ANSI` file format. If I download the zip (which fails to extract) it says `UTF-8`.

Comment: I suspect you have an encoding problem on top of the file handling issues you are seeing. Does the file move from a Windows machine to a Linux based server and finally back to a windows machine?

Comment: The file moves from a windows machine to a linux machine. I can see there in the file contents that they are different from the file on my local machine. I tried using NiFi's functionality to change the encoding but i cannot find ANSI in the possibilities.

Comment: I "solved" this by base64 encoding the zip file before sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to replace text inside the ZIP file itself? I would think the UnpackContent processor should be before Extract/ReplaceText if you're looking to modify the contents.

Comment: I don't want to replace any content! I just want to fetch the zip part of the FlowFile content.

Comment: I updated the question with what happens when skipping the `extract`/`replace` step

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `java.util.zip` to work, you will need compressed content only in the flowfile. Above you quote the contents as including uncompressed content:

```
--e313bde14db343d99c74fbb129fba9ac Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="blabla.zip"
```

When the zip utility encounters that string, it throws an exception. So you did the reasonable thing and tried to strip that metadata out of the flowfile. Unfortunately, that action corrupts the zip content which is why you see that error. Can you change your dataflow to use the ListenHTTP processor? A decent overview of those processors can be found in the NiFi [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/index.html) and a [blog post](https://ddewaele.github.io/http-communication-with-apache-nifi/) about communicating with NiFi via HTTP.

Comment: I read many posts saying the ListenHTTP does not have proper functionality and HandleHttpRequest was the way to go. Does ListenHTTP have a different way of receiving the same message?